# How to install US/European ROM on Chinese Galaxy S7 Edge?

Tags: samsung, stock-rom

I have recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G9350) from China, and there are no Google apps, and I still find a lot of text in Chinese (yes I changed the language), and the apps still contain Chinese.

[image]

I've never dabbled in installing ROMs or even rooting my phones but I'm a very quick learner. Also, I don't mind if the ROM isn't official, I do plan on rooting the phone eventually.

Was there any way to install the US or European ROM on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

European/US ROMs have to be ported in order to work, but there isn't one that I know of, since the majority of us Chinese value Samsung Pay heavily, and with a non-stock ROM Samsung Pay capability is bombed.

However, at the same time, the G9350 variant is also sold in Hong Kong, which has GAPPS, is more internationalized (presumably with English), and with no hardware difference. You could try out one of its [factory firmwares](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-G9350/) by flashing it via Odin. Brief guidance is on the download page.

EDIT: I've seen your screenshot - from the baseband version, it's quite obvious that your device is *not* a G9350 - rather, a G935V (Verizon variant) flashed with ported G9350 firmware (see what I said about ported firmwares?). In this case you need to go with G935V factory firmwares.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113150/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-yan-how-to-install-us-european-rom-on-chinese-galax).