# Samsung galaxy S7 edge from HK soft/firmware

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, stock-android, rom, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I am a massive novice when it comes to this, please can you help? I bought a S7 edge SM-G9350 from hongkong but it did not GooglePlay etc. I live in the UK and wondered how to get my phone software to be the same as UK phones? I saw this [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167105/how-to-install-european-rom-on-chinese-galaxy-s7-edge) but it is a bit advanced for my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the answer will be quite the same as those you referred to. You can try some stock ROMs from Sammobile and check if they have English onboard. If you bother particularly about Google Apps, they can be installed separately.

Comment: thank you. I only need to get access to Google play store. if I can get that then I won't need to change ROM. can you tell me how? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain Gapps [from here](http://opengapps.org/), and then in fact you have two alternatives:

1. Install [custom recovery via Odin](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-install-twrp-recovery-using-odin/) and then flash Gapps with it.
2. Try to install Gapps via `adb sideload`. Not all devices/vendors allow this, but you can try.

   Firstly you need enable ADB, then drop the Gapps zip-archive into folder with ADB and run

   ```
   adb sideload gapps.zip
   ```

There is also manual way of install (described for example [here](https://senk9.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/how-to-install-google-apps-gapps-on-your-android-device-phone/)), but it's rather cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you. I flashed my rom from the China version to HK version, which has googleplaystore. There are some issues now however- can't send SMS, can't use dial pad during calls. Is this a common problem when flashing Roms? Can I flash a UK rom (different model number) onto this phone?

Comment: At least, you can try to flash UK ROM. And **no**, it is NOT common problems, unless the regional versions of phones have significant differences which [might be your case](http://techbeasts.com/list-of-samsung-galaxy-s7-s7-edge-model-numbers/). SM-G9350 seems to be compatible only with SM-G9358, and only *partially*.